# Html5 canvas drag en drop with droppable field

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I want to create an drag and drop function within html5 canvas.

This is want I want:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

But in html5 canvas.

I have searched on the web, but only found drag and drop tutorials without droppable field

Comment: So, you have some elements you've drawn on the canvas, and want to drag those elements?

Comment: Yes, I want to check if it touches an other element.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to display the elements?

Comment: Just to rectangles with space between it

Comment: You might want to look at [kineticjs](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery drag and drop and snap to grid in kineticJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494292/jquery-drag-and-drop-and-snap-to-grid-in-kineticjs)

Answer (score 0):

To drag elements, you have to save the coordinates of the shapes you are drawing.

Here is a nice tutorial from simon sarris  http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

There are different ways of doing this, but if you want something more specific, you'll have to explain us what you really want, or at least post some code. Good luck !